# Mysql Query Refactor Case

Tags: mysql, mariadb, refactoring

Here is my table structure. (MariaDB OR MySql)

| id | data |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | {"one":"1","two":"3"} |
| 2 | {"one":"2","two":"4"} |

I would like to get the output like this

| id | One | Two |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Good | Bad |
| 2 | More Good | Very Bad |

```
Values
1 = Good
2 = More Good
3 = Bad
4 = Very Bad
```

Here is my bad Query in MySQL

```
SET @ONE = 'Good';
SET @TWO = 'More Good';
SET @THREE = 'Bad';
SET @FOUR = 'Very Bad';

SELECT id,

CASE
    WHEN REPLACE(json_extract(data, '$.one'), '"', '') = 1 THEN @ONE
    WHEN REPLACE(json_extract(data, '$.one'), '"', '') = 2 THEN @TWO
    WHEN REPLACE(json_extract(data, '$.one'), '"', '') = 3 THEN @THREE
    WHEN REPLACE(json_extract(data, '$.one'), '"', '') = 4 THEN @FOUR
    ELSE 'NO'
END as One,

CASE
    WHEN REPLACE(json_extract(data, '$.two'), '"', '') = 1 THEN @ONE
    WHEN REPLACE(json_extract(data, '$.two'), '"', '') = 2 THEN @TWO
    WHEN REPLACE(json_extract(data, '$.two'), '"', '') = 3 THEN @THREE
    WHEN REPLACE(json_extract(data, '$.two'), '"', '') = 4 THEN @FOUR
    ELSE 'NO'
END as Two
From TableName;
```

Comment: MySQL or mariaDB? There are now quite a few differences!

Comment: What is **precise** DBMS version?

Answer (score 1):

You could use string functions, like `CONCAT_WS()` to create a comma separated list of all the string variables and `SUBSTRING_INDEX()` to pick the correct value:

```
SET @ONE = 'Good';
SET @TWO = 'More Good';
SET @THREE = 'Bad';
SET @FOUR = 'Very Bad';

SELECT id,
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(
         CONCAT_WS(',', @ONE, @TWO, @THREE, @FOUR),
         ',',
         json_extract(data, '$.one')
       ), ',', -1) One,
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(
         CONCAT_WS(',', @ONE, @TWO, @THREE, @FOUR),
         ',',
         json_extract(data, '$.two')
       ), ',', -1) Two
FROM tablename;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=fc1bcf38e18f277510371636352731dc).

Answer (score 0):

```sql
WITH
dictionary AS ( SELECT 1 id, 'Good' val  UNION ALL
                SELECT 2,    'More Good' UNION ALL
                SELECT 3,    'Bad'       UNION ALL
                SELECT 4,    'Very Bad'  ) 
SELECT test.id, dict_1.val One, dict_2.val Two
FROM test
JOIN dictionary dict_1 ON JSON_EXTRACT(test.data, '$.one') + 0 = dict_1.id
JOIN dictionary dict_2 ON JSON_EXTRACT(test.data, '$.two') + 0 = dict_2.id
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=4e7cee70ca62f4c19936bc2896d1791e

PS. Save "I would like to get the output like this" into separate dictionary table.